# Possible mistake in book Probability

Tags: probability

A four-digit number is selected at random. What is the probability that its ones place is less than its tens place, its tens place is less than its hundreds place, and its hundreds place is less than its thousands place? Note that the first digit of an n-digit number is nonzero.

Book's answer: $$\frac{10\choose4}{9.10^3}$$

My answer:$$\frac{\binom{10}{4}-\binom{9}{3}}{9.10^3}$$
Am I right?

Comment: No, the book is right, because every time you pick a $0$ it automatically goes to the unit place.

Comment: But that is not a 4 digit number i.e. {0,1,3,6} is not a valid combination because the number 0136 is not a four digit number.

Comment: You mean 6310, do you not?

Comment: we want the ones place to be less than the tens place etc

Comment: Indeed.${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Ah I was being stupid. Thanks

Comment: I guess if the question was the opposite then my solution would be correct. Thousands < hundreds <tens <ones